# Checking of internet connection by requesting an image does not work after the image gets cached in the browser

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Checking of internet connection by requesting an image does not work after the image gets cached in the browser. After one or two time, this doesn't work as the image is stored in the browser's cache so is there any solution for that? Or what do I need to check whether a connection is available or not? `window.navigator.online` is not reliable. so looking for the other interesting and reliable solution.

Comment: How reliable do you need it to be? Does it need to predict the users behaviour 2 seconds in the future when they disconnect from the net? (Connectivity is outside of your control - there's no point knowing the answer in most circumstances, since the answer may change before you can act on the answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The perfect solution for checking internet connectivity is to give a ajax call to your server to the dummy page and make that dummy page's entry in the application cache manifest file in the network section so that it may not get cached in the browser, otherwise it wl take that file from browser and show you as online even if u are in offline mode.

Answer (score 3):

Use a cache buster querystring. The querystring forces the browser to check the servver for the new image.

```
yourImageObj.src = "newImage.png?time=" + new Date().getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using XMLHttpRequest object and POST protocol. POST-request does not cached. But this works only if image (or any other resource) loaded from the same domain as page (XMLHttpRequest limitation).

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "url_for_image_file", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xhr.readyState === 4)
      if(xhr.status!==200) {
        // no image loaded
        alert("fail connect to server");
      }
      else {
        alert("connection success");
      }
};
xhr.send(null);
```

Comment: It also assumes that a POST request is processed in the same manner as a GET request, which may not be true.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever. In my tests with IIS and Apache this works. But you are right.

Comment: Thanks for your reply i will try to implement it.